# Have different sorting orders in single column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, data-science

I'm trying to sort a small df by values in two columns, but I need different sorting orders (ascending/descending) for column A (price) depending on the values in column B (action).

So the df looks like this:

| dfindex | price | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0.9 | 'sell' |
| 7 | 0.7 | 'buy' |
| 2 | 0.9 | 'buy' |
| 3 | 0.4 | 'sell' |
| 6 | 0.6 | 'sell' |
| 5 | 0.8 | 'buy' |
| 1 | 0.7 | 'buy' |
| 8 | 0.9 | 'buy' |

My current sorting is via pandas:

```
tx_hist = tx_hist.sort_values(by=['dfindex', 'price'], ascending=[True, False], ignore_index=True)
```

I've also tried a separate sorting function, which takes the 'buy' prices separately, sorts them and inserts them back in the df, but I can't make it work as intended either.

```
def sorttxhist(tx_hist):
    for i in range(len(tx_hist)):
        w = i
        buytxs = []
        selltx = []
        if tx_hist['action'].iloc[w] == 'buy':
            while tx_hist['action'].iloc[w] == 'buy':
                print(buytxs)
                buytxs.append(tx_hist['price'].iloc[w])
                w = w + 1
            buytxs = buytxs.sort(reverse=True)
            tx_hist['price'].iloc[i:w] = buytxs
            #buytxs.clear()

        elif tx_hist['action'].iloc[w] == 'sell':
            while tx_hist['action'].iloc[w] == 'sell':
                print(selltx)
                selltx.append(tx_hist['price'].iloc[w])
                w = w + 1
            selltx = selltx.sort(reverse=False)
            tx_hist['price'].iloc[i:w] = selltx
            print(type(selltx))
    print(tx_hist)
    return tx_hist
```

But it doesn't sort it how I need it, which is a first sort by 'dfindex', and a secondary sort in descending order (price-wise) for 'buy' (in the 'action' col) and in ascending order (price-wise) for 'sell' (in the 'action' col).

So the outcome should look like this:

| dfindex | price | action | Sorting order (not in the df) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0.9 | 'buy' | desc |
| 1 | 0.7 | 'buy' | desc |
| 3 | 0.4 | 'sell' | asc |
| 4 | 0.9 | 'sell' | asc |
| 5 | 0.8 | 'buy' | - / desc |
| 6 | 0.6 | 'sell' | - / asc |
| 8 | 0.9 | 'buy' | desc |
| 7 | 0.7 | 'buy' | desc |

Any help is much appreciated!
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make 2 columns named `sort1` and `sort2` for sorting

`sort1` column divide between group buy and group sell

buy group have negative price in `sort2` column

then sort by `sort1` and `sort2`

```
(df
 .sort_values('dfindex')
 .assign(sort1=df1['action'].ne(df1['action'].shift(1)).cumsum())
 .assign(sort2=df1['price'].mask(df1['action']=="buy", -df1['price']))
 .sort_values(['sort1', 'sort2'])
)
```

output before drop `sort1` and `sort2`

```
    dfindex price   action  sort1   sort2
2   2       0.90    buy     1       -0.90
6   1       0.70    buy     1       -0.70
3   3       0.40    sell    2       0.40
0   4       0.90    sell    2       0.90
5   5       0.80    buy     3       -0.80
4   6       0.60    sell    4       0.60
7   8       0.90    buy     5       -0.90
1   7       0.70    buy     5       -0.70
```

finally drop `sort1` and `sort2`